# Detection of fluent API use

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-interface

Suppose I have the following data model:

```
public class Base {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following `OnModelCreating()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
        .Property(b => b.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(32);
}
```

Is detection of the use of Entity Framework's fluent API possible either at compile or run time? In pseudo-code I would like to do something like:

```
for a given Base
    detect that Name is required and must be <= 32 characters
    act upon that information
```

For context, I am attempting to generate pseudorandom POCOs that conform to the restrictions placed on it by data annotations or the fluent API. Data annotations are simple enough, but I haven't figure out a way to act on the fluent API use.

Comment: Well, you'll have to descend into EF's metadata, but honestly, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to be able to call some method `Gen<Base>()` and get a `Base` object that would successfully save through EF's `SaveChanges()`. I'll look into the EF metadata you mentioned.